# unexpected output for a list loop problem

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, if-statement

The output must be an empty list but I am getting 3. Literaly got confused in this silly problem.

```
j = [2,3,4]
lk = []
for i in j:
    if i>=0:
        j.remove(i)

 

print(j)
```

output = [3]

expected output = []

what is the issue here

Comment: you shouldn't edit the list within it's own iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are looping it is iterating with reference to it's index.

In the first iteration ->
Index is 0 and Value is 2: 2 > 0, the value is getting removed from the list (j). Result: `j=[3,4]`

In the second iteration ->
Index is 1 and value becomes 4 (since you have removed 2 from `j`): 4 > 0, the value is getting removed. Result: `j=[3]`

Now the size of the list is 1 (which is less than the current iterator value(2)), so the iteration stops and the list `j` still has value 3
`j=[3]`

Trial code:

```
j = [2,3,4]
lk = []
for i in j:
    if i>=0:
        j.remove(i)
    print(j)
```

Output:

```
[3, 4]
[3]
```

So, you shouldn't edit the list within it's own iterator. Instead create a copy and perform the operation:

Suggested code:

```
j = [2,3,4]
j_cpy = j.copy()
lk = []
for i in j_cpy:
    if i>=0:
        j.remove(i)
    print(j)

print("Final j value: ", j)
```

Here you are iterating on `j_cpy` and editing the list `j`.

Output:

```
[3, 4]
[4]
[]
Final j value:  []
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda function, they are much simpler, and always work when removing items from lists according to boolean checks.

Example:

```
j = [2, 3, 4]
lk = []
j = list(filter(lambda x: not x >= 0, j))

print(j)
```

Here's a small tutorial on them: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-filter-python-examples/